# JavaScript countdown bug fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database, countdown

Hello thanks for your help, i have made a js count down that was supposed to stop counting once the interval set is elapsed, the count down is working but once the target time reaches, instead it to stop and execute the next task, the count down will then start counting  upwards. please anyone to help me fix this?

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'user/getCurrentPlanAjax',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
          let mining_total = 0;
          let total_balance = 0;
          // $('#total_balance').html("")
          $('#mining_total').html("")
          $('#transaction_current').html("")
          $.each(result, function(e, i) {
              let timeRemaining = '';
              let endTime = new Date(i.ending_time); // Replace with your end time
              let now = new Date();
              let timeDiff = convertTZ(endTime, "America/New_York") - convertTZ(now,
                  "America/New_York");
              console.log(timeDiff, result)
              if (timeDiff <= 0) {
                  timeRemaining = 'Time has expired.';
              } else {
                  let daysRemaining = Math.floor(timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                  let hoursRemaining = Math.floor((timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
                  let minutesRemaining = Math.floor((timeDiff / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                  let secondsRemaining = Math.floor((timeDiff / 1000) % 60);

                  if (daysRemaining > 0) {
                      timeRemaining += daysRemaining + ' day' + (daysRemaining > 1 ?
                          's ' : ' ');
                  }

                  if (hoursRemaining > 0) {
                      timeRemaining += hoursRemaining + ' hour' + (hoursRemaining >
                          1 ? 's ' : ' ');
                  }

                  if (minutesRemaining > 0) {
                      timeRemaining += minutesRemaining + ' minute' + (
                          minutesRemaining > 1 ? 's ' : ' ');
                  }

                  if (secondsRemaining > 0) {
                      timeRemaining += secondsRemaining + ' second' + (
                          secondsRemaining > 1 ? 's' : '');
                  }
              }

              mining_total += Number(i.total_seconds * i.earning_per_seconds);
              // total_balance = Number(i.balance)

              // if (timeRemaining !== 'Time has expired.') {
              let append = '<tr>' +
                  '<td data-label="Plan Name: ">' + i.plan_name + '</td>' +
                  '<td data-label="Remaining time: ">' +
                  '<span class="base--color">' + i.total_second + '</span>' +
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td data-label="Total earning amount: ">' +
                  '<span class="text-success">' + parseFloat((i.total_mining_seconds *
                      i.earning_per_seconds) - (i.total_seconds * i
                      .earning_per_seconds)).toFixed(8) + '</span>' +
                  '</td>' +
                  '</tr>';

              $('#transaction_current').append(append);
              // }

          })

          $('#mining_total').html(parseFloat(mining_total).toFixed(8));
          // $('#total_balance').html(parseFloat(Number(total_balance) + Number(mining_total)).toFixed(8));

      },
  });
}, 900)
```

I have tried declare the `mining_total` variable outside the `setInterval` function to avoid resetting it to zero in each interval.
Move the calculation of `mining_total` outside the `$.each` loop and update it using the accumulated value.
Add a check to stop the countdown and send the accumulated `mining_total` value to the database when the time expires.

```js
let mining_total = 0; // Declare mining_total outside setInterval

setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'user/getCurrentPlanAjax',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            let total_balance = 0;
            // $('#total_balance').html("")
            $('#mining_total').html("");
            $('#transaction_current').html("");

            $.each(result, function(e, i) {
                // Existing code...

                // Calculate mining_total for each item and accumulate
                mining_total += Number(i.total_seconds * i.earning_per_seconds);

                // Existing code...
            });

            if (timeDiff <= 0) {
                // Time has expired
                clearInterval(this); // Stop the countdown

                // Send the accumulated mining_total to the database (total_balance)
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'user/updateTotalBalance',
                    data: {
                        total_balance: mining_total
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        // Handle the success response
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        // Handle the error
                    }
                });

                return; // Exit the function
            }

            // Update the mining_total and total_balance in the HTML
            $('#mining_total').html(parseFloat(mining_total).toFixed(8));
            // $('#total_balance').html(parseFloat(Number(total_balance) + Number(mining_total)).toFixed(8));

        },
    });
}, 900);
```

but not working